# Is log_2(n+1)-log_3(2n+1)=O(1)?

Tags: function, time-complexity, big-o

Is the following claim true? if not how to prove it?

```
log_2(n+1)-log_3(2n+1)=O(1)
```

I think it's probably true from what I have tried.

---

it's true iff there is c,n+0>0 such that `log_2(n+1)-log_3(2n+1) <= c` I don't now log laws but from this step it makes sense to be true

Comment: Care to show us your attempt to proof it?

Comment: @eol will write it

Comment: @eol updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function grows quite slowly, but there is no constant upper bound. So no, the statement is false.

To show this, you do need to know some log laws. The original formula is

[image]

Changing base-3 to base-2 gives us

[image]

Now changing to a common denominator and combining both logs yields

[image]

So the argument inside the log is

[image]

which diverges slowly towards infinity, so the logarithm of that also diverges. And hence the whole function cannot be in O(1).

Comment: you have some mistakes as the third equation is false, where did you the power from?

Comment: @MrCalc No it's correct. The power comes from extending the first term to a common denominator, and then pulling the factor up into the exponent. I just did that in one step.

Comment: Both are right. You posted a different question on the other site.

Comment: @MrCalc How about `a*log(b) = log(b^a)`?

Comment: @MoB. +1, the whole arithmetic is much easier when `x \to \infty`, you end up with `\log_2(x) - \log_3(2x) = a\ln (x) - b` for `a>0` which certainly diverges